# Lightweigth default StreamReader reading nothing

Tags: c#, stream

I am in the need of a default `StreamReader` reading nothing without throwing any exceptions.

How can I efficiently construct such an object?

**Edit** Specifically, if I read from the `StreamReader` object with `ReadLine` I would like to get `null` and no exception.

Comment: Can you ellaborate more on your issue? I answered something and I've droped my answer because I feel I'm answering to who knows what issue :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, I would suggest using `TextReader` as your abstraction level - it's rarely necessary to depend on `StreamReader` directly, as messing around with the underlying stream is generally a bad idea anyway.

If you have code that takes a `TextReader`, you could use

```
Foo(new StringReader(""));
```

If you *really* need a `StreamReader`, you could just pass in an empty `MemoryStream`:

```
Foo(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream()));
```

Comment: I dropped my answer because I'm not sure what OP is talking about. While your answer provides useful info, are you sure OP is talking about this? OP says "I want a StreamReader which doesn't throw exceptions", uhmmm??

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Well reading from an effectively empty stream will cause `Read(char[], int, int)` to return 0, and `Read()` to return -1, without throwing exceptions. I *think* that's what the OP wants...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position to the end of the source stream using `.Seek()` method:

```
this.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
```

If you want some stub for your project you can inherit it from StreamReader:

```
public class EmptyStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    public EmptyStreamReader()
    {

    }

    public EmptyStreamReader(Stream stream): base(stream)
    {

    }

    public override int Read()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override int Peek()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    //and so on - just override all needed methods
}
```